# Inheritance - View of a View

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In my database I have a View which 'inherits' from another View - that is, they return identical columns - only the 'where' clause is different.

Using Linq-to-SQL I end up with two identical Classes (albeit with different TableAttributes). They don't inherit from each other, so I can't use the instance of one Class instead of an instance of the other Class.

Can I force the required Inheritance to be implemented?

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Your question misses a lot of context. The generated classes have no relation, as the generator doesn't do inheritance implications from the schema. If you want to, you'll have to generate your own types and assign those to the views (not sue if Linq-to-SQL can do that, Entity Framework can). Or stay with the generated classes and use AutoMapper.

Comment: I think you are mistakenly projecting OO concepts into SQL Server. A View does not "inherit" from another View; a nested view is more like a "#include" statement. I'm not sure I'd expect Linq-To-Sql to spot this dependency and even if it did, to make any reverse engineering decision from it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I know that sql VIEWs don't actually have inheritance, that's why:
1. I put quotes around 'inherits',
2. I asked if it were possible to force .NET into adding inheritance where it doesn't exist...

In the meantime, I've used .SELECT() to project one object into another... it ain't pretty, but it works ;-)